# I need help to move Javascript p5js translate to be inside the function

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I have the below (tree drawing) code in Javascript. I found it online, I have some more work with it, and I want to include it in a for loop. But I want the translate

```
translate (width / 2, height / 2 );
```

to be inside the function (not in draw). I didn't know how to do it. Can you help me to do that?

[try the code here](https://editor.p5js.org/josefalk/sketches/XEdUurqxt)

```
function setup() 
{
    createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);

}

function draw ()
{
    background (100);
    translate (width / 2, height / 2 );
    branch(80);
}

function branch (len)
{

    
    for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    {
        branch[j] = 
        {
            xPos: -2000 + (j * 200),
            yPos: height/2 + 95
        };    
    }
    
    
    noLoop ();
    angleMode(DEGREES);
    push ();
    if (len > 10)
    {   
        strokeWeight (map(len, 10, 100, 1, 15));
        stroke (70, 40, 20);
        line (0,0,0, -len);
        
        translate (0, -len);
        rotate (random (-20, -30));
        branch (len * random(0.7, 0.9));
        rotate (random (50, 60));
        branch (len * random(0.7, 0.9));
    }
    else
    {
        var r = 80 + random (-20, 20);
        var g = 120 + random (-20, 20);
        var b = 40 + random (-20, 20);
        fill (r, g, b, 150);
        noStroke();
        ellipse (0, 0, 10);
        beginShape ();
        for (var i = 135; i > 40; i--)
        {
            var rad = 15;
            var x = rad * cos (i);
            var y = rad * sin (-i) +20;
            vertex (x,y)
        }
        endShape (CLOSE);
    }
    pop ();

}
```

I need to move the translation to inside the branch function.

Comment: btw you can try the code here
https://editor.p5js.org/josefalk/sketches/XEdUurqxt

Comment: I don't understand what is the problem

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: that's tricky, since branch is a recursive function and you only want the translate to be called one at the beginning. One solution would be to pass a second parameter `firstTime` which you can make true when calling the first time (from draw) and false in the recursive calls (from branch itself). Then you can use a conditional that makes the translation only the first time the function is called.

Comment: Another solution would be to make a class. Then you can put the translate in the constructor, and it will be called once when you instantiate the tree. After that you call the method branch normally. This option is cleaner and better that having a second variable in the branch function.

Comment: Thank you @SembeiNorimaki . Can you provide example how to do it with class because I didn't get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained in the comments, make a second variable so you can know when the function is executed the first time and only then do the translation.

```
function setup() 
{
    createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);    
}

function draw ()
{
    background (100);        
    branch(80, true);
}

function branch (len, firstTime=false)
{
    if (firstTime) {
        translate (width / 2, height / 2 );
    }
    
    for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    {
        branch[j] = 
        {
            xPos: -2000 + (j * 200),
            yPos: height/2 + 95
        };    
    }
    
    
    noLoop ();
    angleMode(DEGREES);
    push ();
    if (len > 10)
    {   
        strokeWeight (map(len, 10, 100, 1, 15));
        stroke (70, 40, 20);
        line (0,0,0, -len);
        
        translate (0, -len);
        rotate (random (-20, -30));
        branch (len * random(0.7, 0.9));
        rotate (random (50, 60));
        branch (len * random(0.7, 0.9));
    }
    else
    {
        var r = 80 + random (-20, 20);
        var g = 120 + random (-20, 20);
        var b = 40 + random (-20, 20);
        fill (r, g, b, 150);
        noStroke();
        ellipse (0, 0, 10);
        beginShape ();
        for (var i = 135; i > 40; i--)
        {
            var rad = 15;
            var x = rad * cos (i);
            var y = rad * sin (-i) +20;
            vertex (x,y)
        }
        endShape (CLOSE);
    }
    pop ();

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I won't be able to do it myself. But I ran into another issue now, This function contains noLoop, so when I move it to my other code, It stops everything in draw function from loop. I tried to add loop () right after that it didn't work. I tried conditional statement as below :

 if (!treeDrawn) 
 {        
     branch(80, true);
  treeDrawn = true;
  angleMode(RADIANS);
  
 } 

it didn't work as well. Any help is appricated.

Comment: please post another question with the updated code of what you have tried.

Comment: I tried, But I need to wait one full day until I can post new question.

Comment: Stackoverflow prevents me from posting another question for several days now.